# Getting flash src after a 302 redirect OR an element inside an embed/object/iframe tag (cross-domain)

Tags: javascript, html, flash, embed, element

The URL example.com/redir will automatically redirect the user (HTTP 302) to example.com/**hi.SWF**?message=Message+Value.

How can I get the message value, using javascript or flash, in the following example?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
         <embed id="foo" src="https://example.com/redir"></embed>
         <!-- Remember that example.com/redir will be automatically redirected to example.com/hi.SWF?message=Message+Value -->

         <!-- The code to get the message value must go here -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Consider that:

1. The above **.html** is hosted in **cross-domain.com**, just like any other file involved in the solution (**.swf**, **.js**, **.html**, **.css**, etc.);
2. You do not have control over **example.com**;
3. You do not have control over **hi.SWF**;
4. You can change the **<embed>** tag to **<object>** or
   **<iframe>**;

Comment: Is there a Flash SWF file involved here? If not, then you can't do anything with Flash.

Comment: @SunilD. Sorry, I edited the question. Now the flash stuff makes sense.

Comment: I believe now the question is much clearer.

Comment: unless i'm forgetting something, you cannot, as that would violate the same-domain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer:

You can't do that, because of the same-origin policy.

User's cookies will not be carried in your request.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest way to get the url of your redirected swf and its parameters, is to use another swf as a loader for your current one, where you can get the url and the parameters passed to your redirected swf and then you can send it to JavaScript via [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

For that, take a look on this example :

**ActionScript :**

```
    // url           : the url of the current swf
    //                 this url is passed by flash vars in the html page
    // default value : http://www.example.com/redirect
var swf_url:String = this.loaderInfo.parameters.url || 'http://www.example.com/redirect',

    // fn            : the name of the js function which will get the url and the message param
    //                 this name is passed by flash vars in the html page
    // default value : console.log
    js_function:String = this.loaderInfo.parameters.fn || 'console.log',

    message:String = 'no message';

var url_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(swf_url);

var swf_loader:Loader = new Loader();
    swf_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_content_load);
    swf_loader.load(url_request);

function on_content_load(e:Event): void 
{   
    var loader_info:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget);

    // get the message param or use the default message
    message = loader_info.parameters.message || message;

    // if ExternalInterface is available, send data to js
    if(ExternalInterface.available)
    {
        // send the swf url and the message param to the js function
        ExternalInterface.call(js_function, { url: loader_info.url, message: message }); 
    }

    // show the redirected loaded swf
    addChild(swf_loader);
}
```

**HTML side :**

For this example, supposed that we have a `.htaccess` file like this :

**.htaccess :**

```
Redirect    /redirect   /new.swf?message=a%20message%20here
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function get_data_from_flash(data)
{
    console.log('url : ' + data.url);
    // gives :
    //      url : http://www.example.com/new.swf?message=a%20message%20here

    console.log('message : ' + data.message);
    // gives :
    //      message : a message here
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="loader.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="url=http://www.example.com/redirect&fn=get_data_from_flash" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="loader.swf" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="flashvars" value="url=http://www.example.com/redirect&fn=get_data_from_flash" />
    </object>
</object>
```

That's all !

If you want more details about how to use `ExternalInterface`, you can take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html).

Hope that can help.